# Cannot load tp_smapi module on thinkpad x60

Tags: linux, laptop, debian, battery, thinkpad

I have an old thinkpad x60 running debian. Recently, I brought a new battery, to check the stats(manufacture-data, first use etc ..) I installed a common program called tlp on the machine. But It looks like the program is not able to load the the modules it needs:

```
 abhiram@x60:~$ sudo tlp-stat -b

 --- TLP 0.6 --------------------------------------------

 +++ ThinkPad Extended Battery Functions
 tp-smapi   = inactive (kernel module 'tp_smapi' load error)
 tpacpi-bat = inactive (unsupported hardware)

 +++ Battery Status
 /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = SANYO  
 /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = 42T4632
 /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
 /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design             =  74880 [mWh]
 /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full                    =  74880 [mWh]
 /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now                     =  11260 [mWh]
 /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =      0 [mW]
 /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Charging
```

After a few google searches, I found out that most of the battery control interface is provided by the tp_smapi module. So I tried manually loading it without much success.

```
abhiram@x60:~$ sudo modprobe tp_smapi
ERROR: could not insert 'tp_smapi': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

From dmesg:

```
 8622.496729] thinkpad_ec: Unknown symbol dmi_check_system_2 (err 0)
```

According to the [tp-smapi](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi#Model-specific_status) wiki the module should work with the think-pad x60. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly solution, I got it to work when the switched to Arch Linux. In retrospect, I might have been able to fix the problem by moving to a different kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problem with battery threshold after following the instruction for installing TLP. My ThinkPad X200T is running Xubuntu 14.04. To solve the problem I searched the solution in this website https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/tp-smapi#Inkompatible-Hardware and then i did these steps:

1. copy this in terminal to open mousepad as root: sudo mousepad /etc/modprobe.d/tp-smapi.conf
2. copy this in mousepad: options thinkpad_ec force_io=1
3. save
4. type: sudo tlp stat -b

After those steps tp-smapi should be now active.